# Has anyone encountered horizontal white lines on their plots using ggplot2 in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization, data-analysis

I tried to make plots for my data analysis task, however when I try to create a filled bar chart, I always end up with a bar chart that no longer looks pleasing.

My code snippet

```
ggplot(day_sales, mapping = aes(x = day, y = total_sales, fill = lifestage)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = my_palette) +
  theme_minimal() +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(title = "Customer Type")) +
  xlab("Weekday") +
  ylab("Total Sales") +
  labs(title = "Weekday Purchase Behaviour: Customer Lifestage Analysis") +
  theme(panel.grid.major.x = element_blank())
```

What I expected
[ggplot expected image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQPGC.png)

What I got
[ggplot code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SyBXw.jpg)

Comment: This is usually one of two things: (1) raster images can hint at lines/artifacts, and saving to a vector-based format such as SVG or PDF will not show those problems; or (2) your data is heavy with duplicated levels, so it is plotting a lot of small bars. It would be easier to determine which of those problems are applicable here if we had reproducible data such as posting the output from `dput(head(day_sales,30))` (or some size, not all please); see https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269 , [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info for more options. Thanks!

Comment: I'd suspect it's the latter of those two problems - you have multiple rows for each combination of day/lifestage and R is plotting one very slim rectangle for each row stacked on top of each other. Unfortunately, the linked answer above I think won't give you a working solution as I presume you're summing `total_sales` to get bar heights? I would suggest `stat_summary(fun = sum, geom = "bar", position = "stack")` as a line to do all of that, or sum variables before plotting.